# connecting odbc driver to hive

Tags: hive, cloudera

I am getting error while connecting to the ODBC driver cloudera

[image: hive odbc connection]

i have got the ip address from command  **ifconfig**

```
 Error returned trying to set default as the initial database:
 No more data to     read.; Also tried quoting the database name 
`default` but the query failed with the following error: No more data to read.
```

Comment: If config from which machine. check if telnet working on machine ie   telnet 192.168.153.153 10000   is working or not  link have full documentation  read it http://hortonworks.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/Product-Guide-HDP-2.1-v1.01.pdf

Answer (score -1):

connect method : Amazon Hive ODBC Driver
connect specitication: port 10000, database : hive and write a username, password
Test Connect
Congratuation > then you can click the submit button